# proxy server test in c#

Tags: c#, proxy

I am making a web request using a proxy

```
HttpWebRequest wr = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(inputURL);
WebProxy proxy = new WebProxy(101.1.1.1,80);

wr.Headers.Set(HttpRequestHeader.AcceptLanguage, "en-US");
wr.Timeout = 100000;
wr.Method = "GET";
wr.ContentType = "text/html;charset=UTF-8";
```

When I look in Fiddler, I do not see any proxy information. How can I make sure proxy is being used correctly?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
string proxyIP = "61.135.178.114";
int proxyPort = 80;

var req = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("http://ip-api.com/json");
req.Proxy = new WebProxy(proxyIP, proxyPort);
var resp =   req.GetResponse();
var json = new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();

var myip = (string)JObject.Parse(json)["query"];

if (myip == proxyIP)
{
    MessageBox.Show("OK...");
}
```

You will need [Json.Net](https://json.codeplex.com/) library to run this code

Comment: var myip = (string)JObject.Parse(json)["query"]; what is query?

Comment: Because that API returns the caller's ip address in that field. Just print the `json` to see what it returns..